# Mac App Store and Plugins

Tags: cocoa, macos, app-store, mac-app-store

I saw this in the Mac App Store guidelines:

> 2.16: Apps that download or install additional code or resources to add
>   functionality or change their primary
>   purpose will be rejected

Does this mean that applications that use plug-ins would be rejected? I did some research and couldn't come up with anything, but apps like Opera on the App Store supports extensions, so I'm thinking either it's allowed (to a certain extent) or there's inside deals going on. The clause seems to be rather specific to code that the **app itself** downloads and installs, not 3rd party plugins installed by users.

Does anyone have an app in the store with plugin support? Or can someone clarify this clause?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to disagree with @Anomie's answer.

The [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html) at point 2.16 states

> Apps that download or install additional code or resources to add
>   functionality or change their primary purpose will be rejected

that seems to affirm that you cannot include plugin systems.

But the [Mac Developer Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/mac/mac_program_agreement_20120216.pdf) at point 3.3.2 states

> An Application may install or run additional interpreted or executable code (e.g., plug-ins and extensions) for use in conjunction with the Application as long as such code:
>
> - does not change the Application’s submitted binary or would not otherwise be considered an Update (as determined in Apple’s sole discretion); and
> - does not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the Mac App Store.

I've collected some informations and there are applications in the Mac App Store ([Courier](http://itunes.apple.com/it/app/courier/id402452048?mt=12) is one of them) that have a plugin system. The key point is that the user action is required.

Courier doesn't have any included plugin list or integrated downloader, but you can go to their [website](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/courier/) and download the plugins. Then double click on the downloaded icon and it will automatically add the plugin to the mac app.

Comment: hey @MacTeo, great answer, but if they forbid to change Apps submitted binary, how do apps on the appStore update themselves?

Comment: The main binary doesn't need to change. You can provide bundles with dynamic libraries and interface loaded at runtime. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html

Comment: Courier app disappeared, why is that ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means apps that use plugins would be rejected. As for Opera, I'd bet on "inside deals"; if you're big enough or know the right people, you can probably get exceptions for many of the rules. There's also the fact that some reviewers may let things slide that others won't, which leads to the phenomenon witnessed in the iPhone app store that an app can be accepted and then a new version that changes nothing can be rejected. Or vice versa.

I expect the intent of that rule is that Apple wants to maintain an iron fist over what is allowed, so possible loopholes that might allow an app to get through to the public and then transform into something Apple doesn't like must be closed.

Comment: There's a loophole in the clause text itself, though. "Apps that download or install additional code" makes it seem like "Apps" is the subject, so that would not cover a human decision to download and install something.

Comment: Remember though that it isn't a legal system, Apple can change the rules at their whim. And it wouldn't surprise me if there is an "any other reason we see fit" clause in there somewhere, too.

Comment: Went through it and there's no such clause, but yeah Apple can do whatever they want.

Answer (score 1):

Aperture, Pixelmator and Logic support plugins and are sold on the AppStore.
I think that as long as your app does not download the plugins automatically supporting plugins is not a violation of the guidelines.